# How to merge a list of objects using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class defined below

```
public class ResultClass()
{
    public HashSet<string> VerifiedResults { get;  private set; }
    public HashSet<string> UnverifiedResults { get;  private set; }
    bool IsBlocked {get; private set; }
}
```

If I have a list containing items for ResultClass, for eg., `List<ResultClass>()` , how can I combine the results into a single ResultClass object using LINQ.

Is a way to do what my code below does, but with LINQ, instead?

```
var finalResult = new ResultClass();
foreach(var item in listOfResultClass)
{
    finalResult.VerifiedResults.Union(item.VerifiedResults);
    finalResult.UnverifiedResults.Union(item.UnverifiedResults);
    finalResult.IsBlocked = item.IsBlocked;
}
```

Comment: Since the code in the question does not do anything useful (and probably does not even compile) any LINQ call should do... Like no-op `Union` calls in the question - just keep one and that should satisfy your request... Please decide if you need help getting that code to do something useful or just refactoring suggestions for working (which probably would be better on CR instead of SO... also you'd need to get code working/compiling first)

Comment: You can use `SelectMany` as an alternative to the for loop , but other than that, you either implement your own extension, or use `AutoMapper` which is a better approach for objects mapping and projection.

Comment: I find interesting how you are assigning IsBlocked to the combined resultClass.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It is very obvious that the snippet I pasted is NOT a fully working code. You comment doesn't make any sense other than just stating the obvious. Please refrain from commenting if you don't have anything good to add.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using the LINQ [Aggregate function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=net-7.0), as can be seen in following example:

```
public class ResultClass
{
   public HashSet<string> VerifiedResults { get; set; } = new();
   public HashSet<string> UnverifiedResults { get; set; } = new();
   public bool IsBlocked { get; set; } = false;
}


internal class Program
{
   private static void Main()
   {
      var results = GetResults();

      var finalResult = results.Aggregate(new ResultClass(), (r, next) =>
      {
         r.IsBlocked = r.IsBlocked || next.IsBlocked;
         r.VerifiedResults.UnionWith(next.VerifiedResults);
         r.UnverifiedResults.UnionWith(next.UnverifiedResults);
         return r;        
       });
}

private static List<ResultClass> GetResults()
{
    return new List<ResultClass>()
    {
      new ResultClass()
      {
         VerifiedResults = new HashSet<string>{"first", "second" },
         UnverifiedResults = new HashSet<string>{"third" },
         IsBlocked = false
      },
      new ResultClass()
      {
         VerifiedResults = new HashSet<string>{"first", "fourth" },
         UnverifiedResults = new HashSet<string>{"fifth" },
         IsBlocked = true
      },
      new ResultClass()
      {
         VerifiedResults = new HashSet<string> (),
         UnverifiedResults = new HashSet<string>{"sixt", "seventh" },
         IsBlocked = false
      }
    };
  }
```

}

A few remarks:

- I adapted your `ResultClass` to remove compiler errors and to make it possible to initialize a list of them easily.
- for the `'IsBlocked` property, I used the logical OR of all the individual `IsBlocked` properties.
- You should use `UnionWith` rather than `Union` in this case.
- It might be a good idea to think about possible conflicts where the same string occurs in different `ResultClass` instances, both in 'verified' and 'unverified' properties. It may be necessary to adapt the accumulator lambda expression to get the results you want.

Comment: For OP: Please note that the `ResultClass` now has `= new();` on both `Verified-/Unverified-Results`. You need this for the Aggregate to properly work.

Answer (score 1):

As @iSR5 mentioned, you can use `SelectMany`. I am not sure how do you plan to assign the `IsBlocked`, but this seems to behave like your code:

```cs
var result = new ResultClass()
{
    VerifiedResults = new HashSet<string>(results.SelectMany(x => x.VerifiedResults)),
    UnverifiedResults = new HashSet<string>(results.SelectMany(x => x.UnverifiedResults)),
    IsBlocked = results.LastOrDefault().IsBlocked,
};
```

Also, please read @Johan Donne comments.